# Can Neural Network be used to predict a set in a certain time stamps

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, prediction

I have a market transactions dataset including time stamps and goods as follow.

John always buy milk and bread in Super Market. Besides that, he also buys some goods like the following:

- On Monday, John bought milk, bread {beer, chocolate}.
- On Tuesday, John bought milk, bread {potato}.
- On Wednesday, John bought milk, bread {chocolate, avocado, peanuts}.

Can we answer the question: "What will he buy on Thursdays?".

For example: He will buy {beer, avocado} besides milk and bread on Thursdays.

I think it is a kind of multiple regression. Which model can I use to predict a set of goods in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question than it is a Multi-Label classification.

You have some input features (dayofweek, HasBoughtMilk HasBoughtBread etc). And you want to predict several other labels (Beer, Avocado) based on them. You could do this with sklearn easily, it supports multilabel classification.

If you want to consider what was bought on previous days (since it could affect your labels) you could do this in 2 ways:

1) Add synthetic features like binaries which show 'HasBoughtBread this week already'
2) Or use RNNs which are good at handling time series.

Comment: There are a lot of goods in dataset. We can not label each good in dataset. Furthermore, we can not make sure that our labels are perfect. How about combining unsupervised learning and time series?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are exposing seems to be a textbook case for Random Forests. The inference rules you are trying to express fit really well in decision trees. Random Forests would provide you with a flexible model and fast to train.

Of course this not the only way, you could use SVMs or some deep learning like RNNs, but it feel like using a bazooka to swat a fly for me.

Cheers,

Quentin

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the actual factors you're trying to model.  Are some items dependent on one another?  Is there an actual time element in the data, or are we just conditioned to infer it?

Assuming that you have a time element, you will definitely want some order of time-series analysis, a sequencing of purchases, perhaps with actual time lags.  For instance, if John doesn't go to the store one day, what happens to his purchases?  Do we need to learn how often some things get bought?  Does one product purchase hasten or delay another?

These considerations suggest either pre-processing the data (for time lags) or a RNN, LSTM, or Q-net delay of some sort.  Naive Bayes or Random Forest might be of some help, but you'd still need to pre-process the time relations first.

Comment: I think: time-series analysis can answer the question: "When will John go to super market?". My question is find relationship between goods and time. Can we infer a set of goods by given a time stamps?.

Comment: Time series is also good to predict "When will John next need to buy coffee?"  You can then select by day to get the predicted shopping list.